# Hierarchical clustering on continuous heterogeneous variables with different range/scales in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, bioinformatics, correlation, hierarchical-clustering

I would like to use R to perform hierarchical clustering with two groups of variables describing the same samples. One group is microarray gene expression data (for specific genes) that have been normalized and batch effect corrected. The other group also has some quantitative clinical parameters that describe the same samples. However, these clinical variables have not been normalized or subjected to any kind of transformation(i.e. raw continuous values).

For example, one variable of these could have range of values from 2 to 35, whereas another from 0.1 to 0.9, etc.

Thus, as my ultimate goal in to implement hierarchical clustering and use both groups simultaneously (merged in a matrix/dataframe), in order to inspect which of these clinical variables cluster with specific genes, etc:

1) Is an initial transformation in the group of the clinical variables necessary before merging with the genes and perform the clustering ? For example: log2 transformation, which has also been done to part of my gene expression data !!

2) Or, a row scaling (that is the total features in the input data) would take into account this discrepancy ?

3) For a similar analysis/approach, like constructing a correlation plot of the above total variables, would a simple scaling be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Without having seen your gene expression data, I can only provide you some general suggestions based on your description, in the context of the 3 questions you asked:

1) You should definitely check the distribution of each group. In R, you may use one or more of the following function to visualize the distribution:

```
hist(expression_data) ##histogram
plot(density(expression_data)) ##density plot; alternative to histogram
qqnorm(expression_data); qqline(expression_data) #QQ plot
```

Since my understanding is that one of your expression data group is log2 transformed, that particular group should have a normal distribution (i.e. a bell curve shape in the histogram and a straight line in the QQ plot). Whether to transform the group that has not yet been transformed will depend on what you want to do with the data. For instance, if you want to use a t-test to compare the two groups, then you definitely need a transformation, as there is a normality assumption associated with a t-test. With regard to hierarchical clustering, if you decide to use both groups in a single clustering analysis, then why would you ever keep one transformed and the other not?

2) Scaling by features is a reasonable approach. [Here](http://math.usu.edu/jrstevens/stat5570/2.3.Clustering.pdf) is a clustering lecture from a Utah State Univ. stats course, with an example. `scale=TRUE` is an option for you if you decide to use `heatmap` function in R.

3) I don't think there is a definitive answer to your third question. It has to depend on how many available features you have and what analyses you will be doing downstream. Similar to question 1, I would argue that simple scaling may be sufficient for visualizing your data by hierarchical clustering. However, do keep in mind that, say you decide to perform a linear model (which is very common with microarray gene expression data), you might want to consider more sophisticated data scaling.

Comment: Dear David, thank you for your answers !! Regarding each one separately: 1) My main goal is to just cluster my samples with both groups of variables. I have already performed statistical testing to find DE genes (my samples are paired, for each patient one cancer and control sample, and also the clinical variables for the same sample). The issue as mentioned from some collaborators, is if scaling is enough. In other words, if i just merge the two groups and perform then row scaling, maybe it is not totally correct, regarding afterwards the range of values in the heatmap ? (i.e -2, 2) ?

Comment: My notion for this, is because the values of these clinical variables are not log2-transformed, when i scale the rows totally (row scaling), which includes both genes and these parameters, perhaps then the scaling values are not representative of the changes ? in the meaning of proportional (in the context of log2 transform) ? and i should first somehow transform my clinical variables separately, and then merge them with my genes ? For instance, if the distribution of my clinical variables is  not ~normal, log2 transform/boxcox, etc, and then row scaling ?

Comment: Regarding 2 & 3: thank you also for the tutorial provided, i have also read it in the past. For heatmap creation, i use the ComplexHeatmap R package. For the correlation plot (supplementary to the heatmap), i would like to inspect any possible strong correlations of any of my clinical variables with any of my genes-in total i have 94 selected genes and 8 clinical continuous parameters

Comment: @Jason Great that you have attempted to identify diff. expressed genes. You certainly should not transform clinical variables (sorry I may have missed this in the original answer). I thin whether scaling is enough is a question of whether you can justify it. Also, you may want to check microarray literature (specifically, material/methods sections) to see if anyone has done similar scaling procedures before. It'll be good if you can find literature citation to backup your approach.

Comment: Dear David, thank you again for your response !! Yes, the main question/issue as you pinpointed, is whether scaling should be enough after merging the two groups of variables-or, an initial transformation on the PET variables alone, would be essential. I'm also currently searching literature as you mentioned, but it remains still a bit complex.

Comment: No problem. One more advice if your approach isn't well documented. If your institution/company has a statistical consulting group/specialist, you should consider bring your question and your proposed method, and **explain it** to that group/person. This will allow stat expert to spot potentially problematic issues and give you the most appropriate advice. Good luck!